# Resize DraggableFlatList when rows are hidden?

Tags: react-native, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I'm using the excellent package [react-native-draggable-flatlist](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist).

It has an `isActive` property that becomes true when a drag starts. I'm using it to set css `display: none` on some rows when the category is `LongPressed`.

The goal is to make drag/drop by top level category easier.  However, the rows are still taking up space.

I'm hoping to (in this example) get Sleep and Energy to be right on top of each other before the drag starts.

[image]

Is there something simple I'm missing to get the list to resize when the rows are hidden?